# Bokeh not rendering, stuck on Loading BokehJS

Tags: python, jupyter, bokeh

Yesterday I had Bokeh version 0.12 or something like that. I decided to upgrade to version 2.0.2 and it seems to have been a terrible mistake. Now I cannot even plot the simplest things.
I do the imports as follows and try to plot just a simple line

```
from bokeh.models import Slider, ColumnDataSource, Button, Panel, Tabs, CategoricalColorMapper, HoverTool, Select
from bokeh.io import push_notebook,  output_notebook, reset_output
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show #, output_file
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, row, column
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
# from bokeh.resources import INLINE
# import bokeh.io

# bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)

from numpy.random import random
import sys


# output_notebook()
output_notebook()#hide_banner=True)  #Este comando se necesita para hacer el embedding the los plots!!!!!
```

This just gives `Loading BokehJS ...` and the jupyter cell moves on to the next one but it doesn't successfully loads Bokeh. Then, trying to run

```
p = figure()
p.line(x=[2,4,5,6,7], y=[3,4,5,7,9])
show(p)
```

does nothing...

As you can tell I have already tried the solution `bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)` but it just doesn't do the trick.

When running `!bokeh info` in the jupyter notebook I get:

````
Python version      :  3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython version     :  7.6.1
Tornado version     :  6.0.3
Bokeh version       :  2.0.2
BokehJS static path :  c:\users\cuspi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\static
node.js version     :  (not installed)
npm version         :  (not installed)```
````

Comment: If you open the JS console in your browser, does it show any errors?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: It differs by every browser type and by platform. You will have to do a web search to see how to access the JavaScript console on your OS/browser. You could also try other browsers and report back what happens.

Comment: Right. When I run the JS console I get some errors:
```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed_items_notebook' of undefined
    at embed_document (<anonymous>:6:20)
    at <anonymous>:10:5
    at <anonymous>:26:3
    at window._Events.handleAddOutput (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:763), <anonymous>:76:60)
    at window._Events.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at window._Events.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
    at window._Events.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)...
```

Comment: And this one:

```Uncaught TypeError: Bokeh.set_log_level is not a function
    at inline_js (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:763), <anonymous>:258:13)
    at run_inline_js (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:763), <anonymous>:271:20)
    at eval (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:763), <anonymous>:293:7)
    at eval (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:763), <anonymous>:179:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at run_callbacks (eval at append_javascript (outputarea.js:763), <anonymous>:177:36)
  at ...```

Comment: That indicates BokehJS is not, in fact, loaded. However, I can't reproduce any issue with your code above on OSX with Safari or Windows with Edge or Chrome, with either CDN or INLINE resources. If you are willing and able to participate in the process of OSS to help us reproduce the issue (a necesary first step) then I would suggest filing a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues). Otherwise I can only offer general suggests to vary things and see what is affected: try clear cache, force reload, other browsers, other notebook versions, jupyterlab, etc.

Comment: I am using jupyter notebooks on chrome, on windows 10 with anaconda. When everything stopped working, I upgraded with `pip`. Now I have upgraded from anaconda prompt. Does that help or gives any clue?

Comment: Not really. I suggested several things above that you can try, in order to get more information. For instance, an important first question: is this only a Chrome issue? Or does it affect other browsers for you? What about non-windows systems?  Does cache clear help? The scope of the problem has to be narrowed down by experimentation so that there is some hope other people can reproduce it. It will likely take some back and forth, and time. That is the nature of OSS -- a process, and a collaboration. But the issue tracker is the appropriate place to iterate on this discussion, not SO comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have now raised an [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10002)